# create and add Event Receiver in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

How to create and add Event Receiver.I need to give permission for view my item which was added by me in SPList.Likewise i should not give permission to view my item in the same SPList.I have to set permission programatically..plz help me..

Comment: You can set read parameter to list item only for owner item. Why set-it programmatically ?

Answer (score 1):

See [Creating SharePoint 2010 Event Receivers in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010.aspx).

Within ItemAdded, you can call [BreakRoleInheritance(false)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee550474.aspx) on `properties.ListItem` to enable custom permissions for the item and clear the existing permissions. You can then use code like the following to add the new permission settings:

```
public void AddRoleAssignment(SPWeb web, SPUser user, SPListItem item, SPRoleType roleType)
{
    SPRoleDefinition role = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleType);
    SPRoleAssignment assignment = new SPRoleAssignment(user);
    assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(role);
    item.RoleAssignments.Add(assignment);
}
```